# Spread operator for a variable of arrays of different types returns an array of a union of those types

Tags: typescript, types

In Typescript, when spreading a variable of type `number[] | string[] | boolean[]`, the resulting variable is of type `(number | string | boolean)[]`:

```
const a: number[] | string[] | boolean[] = [];

const b = [...a] //Type of b is now (number | string | boolean)[];
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhmArgWwEYFMBOBtAXRgB8ZocBLMAc0JJgxBABss4w6BeGQgbgCh+oSLAwxueAHTS4BIA)

This was unexpected to me. I would have expected the type of `b` to be `number[] | string[] | boolean[]`. Does someone know why this would be the case?

Comment: `a[0]` is `number | string | boolean`, so it's not necessarily surprising that this would be the result, just perhaps undesirable.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Good point, I didn't think about that.

Comment: I haven't found an existing issue, but my suspicion from looking at other issues is that an array literal is, by default, widened to a single unordered array type.  Part of this is because people often want that with their array literals.  If you write `const b = [...a] as const` you'll get something closer to what you want (although it'll be `readonly`).  There's also the general limitation that there's no such thing as ["distributive control flow analysis"](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) so the compiler does not evaluate `[...a]` three times; it just evaluates it once.

Comment: This latter behavior is especially relevant if you write `[...a, ...a]`, even with `as const` the compiler does not say "okay, either all `number`, or all `string` or all `boolean`".  It gives you the full expanded union containing erroneous cross-terms like `readonly (string | number)[]`.  In any case I don't know how to write an authoritative answer to this since it's mostly just guesswork in the absence of specific documentation or GitHub issue.

Comment: Ah, found https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28813, which just says "we don't distribute spreads across unions like this" and "just use `slice()`", and the only reason is "In other places where we would have to special-case a union type only existing in one place, we don't", presumably because of performance?  Anyway I can write up an answer if you agree with the analysis here.  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, you can write up an answer if you want. What you've said seems to be all the information we have on the matter right now so it's as close to the answer as we can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be intended that the outcome of an array spread will become a single array type even if the original array's type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of array types.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#28813](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28813) for more details.

I think that as a human being, you look at `[...a]` and see it as a single "copy" operation on `a`; but the compiler treats it more generally to support things like `[1, ...a, 2]` or `[...a, ...a]`, etc.  So the shortcut that `[...a]` should have type `typeof a` is not taken.

The issue at microsoft/TypeScript#28813 mentions that there are other places in TypeScript where unions do not propagate upward out of properties or downward into them exactly where someone might expect.  For example, taking something like `declare const x: {a: 0, b: 0} | {a: 1, b: 1}` and copying it into a new object literal like `const y = {a: x.a, b: x.b}` will result in the new object type being `{a: 0 | 1, b: 0 | 1}` even though ostensibly it should be the same type as the original.  The compiler simply does not distribute its analysis across all unions, since this would be prohibitively expensive in general.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) for a declined suggestion to allow developers to opt in to such analysis on an as-needed basis.)  For array spreads this means that there's no general mechanism to support `[...a, ...a]` being interpreted as `number[] | string[] | boolean[]`.

So that's what's happening and why.

---

As for alternatives, there was some work done on array spread with [variadic tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) so if you use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to prevent widening of your array types, you will get something closer to what you're looking for:

```
const c = [...a] as const;
// const c: readonly number[] | readonly string[] | readonly boolean[]
```

Or, as you have discovered, and as [mentioned in microsoft/TypeScript#28813](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28813#issuecomment-472639888), you can use `slice()`:

```
const d = a.slice();
// const d: number[] | string[] | boolean[]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLhmArgWwEYFMBOBtAXRgB8ZocBLMAc0JJgxBABss4w6BeGQgbgCh+oSLAwxueAHTS4BfgHp5MYdAZIAFOSrV6qTLnqMWbMAEpCglbGDie0ybPgRl4aAMUuRypDjYATcGYAT2R0bHwiUl84ALBgsihKGjoo-0CQo1Z2CyFXWD9bOEkIZgpgLHVTdyUrGD8kPXCUhKTaSIYmLI45fj8sYGY4X09VAA8kAG94JAAGABo1GBmYAF96KcQYAEYFjCQt1dyvEO4NpFGHXfPJMRX3ACoR2CDJ-hh36aX6LYEPxeXSD9+Gt7vIgA)